# Proving a topological space is path connected

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Suppose $(X,T_X)$ is a topological space and $\infty_X \notin X$. Write $X^* = X \cup \{\infty_X\}$ and suppose the open sets of $X^*$ the empty set and the union of an open set in $X$ and the point $\{\infty_X\}$.

I want to show that $(X^*,T_X^*)$ is a path connected space. This means I have to show that there is a single path connected component ($X^*$ itself), i.e. that for any $x,y \in X^*$ there is a continuous map $\gamma: I \rightarrow X$ where $\gamma(0) = x, \gamma(1)=y$. Here is $I=[0,1]$ equipped with the Euclidean topology.

I don't really have a clue how to proceed, should I do something with the fact that $\gamma$ is continuous and work with the definition? I'm guessing that the special point $\{\infty_X\}$ has an important role to show path connectedness but I am confused because we don't have any information on the connectedness of $X$.

EDIT: Can we conclude from this that any topological space can be embedded as a closed subspace of a path connected topological space? If so, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x\in X$ and define $\gamma\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow X$ by$$\gamma(t)=\begin{cases}\infty_X&\text{ if }t\in[0,1)\\x&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Then $\gamma(0)=\infty_X$ and $\gamma(1)=x$. Besides, $\gamma$ is continuus since, if $A$ is an open subset of $X$:

- If $\infty_X,x\notin A$, $\gamma^{-1}(A)=\emptyset$, which is an open subset of $[0,1]$;
- If $\infty_X\in A$ and $x\notin A$, $\gamma^{-1}(A)=[0,1)$, which is an open subset of $[0,1]$;
- If $\infty_X,x\in A$, $\gamma^{-1}(A)=[0,1]$, which is an open subset of $[0,1]$.

Since you cannot have $x\in A$ and $\infty_X\notin A$, this proves that $\gamma$ is continuous. And $\gamma$ is a path from $\infty_X$ to $x$. Since there is such a path for every $x\in X$, $X$ is path-connected.

Comment: What about $x,y \neq \infty_X$? It seems to me you only constructed paths with $\infty_X$...

Comment: You take a path from $x$ to $\infty_X$, followed by a path from $\infty_X$ to $y$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! cheers!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Or directly, $\gamma(0)=x$, $\gamma(1)=y$, and $\gamma(t)=\infty_X$ otherwise

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Nice!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have an extra question about this problem. I've edited my post above. Would you be able to have a look? thanks!

Comment: What you did proves that $X$ can be embedded (as a closed subspace) in $X^*$, which is a path connected topological space.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I know that an embedding is a continuous injection which induces a homeomorphism onto its image, but I don't see why that is the case here...

Comment: That's because the open sets of $X$ are exactly the open sets when we see $X$ as a subspace of $X^*$.

Comment: Did you find some error in my answer?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I still don't see why this embedding is true using my definition. Could you help?

Comment: If $A$ is an open subset of $X$, then $A=(A\cup\{\infty_X\}\cap X$, and therefore $A$ is open with respect to the subspace topology. And if $A$ is open with respect to the subspace topology, then $A=A^*\cap X$ for some open subset $A^*$ of $X^*$. If $A^*=\emptyset$, then $A=\emptyset$; otherwise, $A^*=B\cup\{\infty_X\}$ for some open subset $B$ of $X$, and then $A=A^*\cap X=B\in T_X$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos but don't we have to find a continuous injection? Maybe it's obvious but I don't see how this related to the definition i gave of an embedding...

Comment: The continuous injection is the identity map from $X$ into $X^*$ ($x\mapsto x$).